# Can a typeclass constraint be used in a newtype definition?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, newtype

Suppose we have the following `newtype` definition:

```
newtype A = A { _run :: Monad m => A -> [Int] -> m Int }
```

This does not compile with GHC 8.0.2:

```
error: Not in scope: type variable ‘m’
```

Replacing `m` with a concrete typeclass like `IO` or `[]` does compile, as I would expect. Given that this is ok, why does GHC not allow the signature above? What is wrong with adding a typeclass constraint inside of this `newtype`?

Comment: The following declaration works: `newtype A = A { _run :: A -> [Int] -> (forall m. Monad m => m Int) }` (requires `{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}` extension).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
newtype A = A { _run :: forall m. Monad m => A -> [Int] -> m Int }
```

It's hard to tell what you want to do, but this isn't very usable. Any value of type `A` needs to work for all monads (you don't get to choose).

This is also possible, with the same restrictions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
data A where A :: Monad m => (A -> [Int] -> m Int) -> A
```

But perhaps you mean something more like

```
newtype A m = A { _run :: A m -> [Int] -> m Int }
```

This allows for values of different types of `A` using different monads.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot more sense to me now. Is there any meaningful difference between the RankNTypes approach and GADT approach?

Comment: @BillM Aside from a typo (fixed) and no name like `_run`? No.

Comment: @ephemient I tried it in GHCi, and with my definition of `f` below, the GADTs way worked, but the RankNTypes way had an error.

Comment: I'm not sure how editing other people's answers works, but I edited it to that respect.

Comment: I tried it more in GHCi, and whenever I tried to access the function member from the GADTs definition, it complained that `type variable ‘m’ would escape its scope` -- I think this way won't work.

Comment: There is a huge difference between the `data` and `newtype` versions.  They mean different things entirely.  The `data` version creates an existential. Whenever you apply the constructor, you lose the type `m`, and it can never be recovered.  The `newtype` version is universal. The value held by the constructor must be polymorphic across all `m` with a `Monad` instance.  When you extract it, you can use it for any `m`.

Answer (score 8):

It depends on what you're trying to store in `A`.

If you're trying to store any function like that, as long as `m` is a `Monad`, use it as a type parameter, and specify this contraint in your functions:

```
newtype A m = A { _run :: A m -> [Int] -> m Int }

myFunction :: Monad m => A m -> A m
```

You could then have things like `A [] -> [Int] -> [Int]` or `A Maybe -> [Int] -> Maybe Int` inside the constructor.

```
f :: A Maybe -> [Int] -> Maybe Int
f _ (x:_) = Just x
f _ [] = Nothing

g :: Monad m => A m -> [Int] -> m Int
g _ xs = return $ head xs

myA :: A Maybe
myA = A f  -- this works

myOtherA :: Monad m => A m
myOtherA = A g  -- this works too
```

---

On the other hand, if you want to force the data you store to be polymorphic, you can use the GHC extension `RankNTypes`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
newtype A = A { _run :: forall m. Monad m => A -> [Int] -> m Int }

myFunction :: A -> A
```

You couldn't have things like `A -> [Int] -> [Int]` or `A -> [Int] -> Maybe Int` within the constructor, because the `forall` forces them to be general over **any** `Monad m`, so it would have to be of type `Monad m => A -> [Int] -> Maybe Int`.

```
f :: A -> [Int] -> Maybe Int
f _ (x:_) = Just x
f _ [] = Nothing

g :: Monad m => A -> [Int] -> m Int
g _ xs = return $ head xs

myA :: A
myA = A f  -- this does not work ; it wants forall m. Monad m => m, not []

myOtherA :: A
myOtherA = A g  -- this does work
```

This will only really be useful if you intend to use different specific `Monad` instances for an `A`-value.  For example, Lenses work this way by using different functors to do different things to the lens.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying how to write the constructor and making the connection to Lenses, this made a bunch of things click for me.

Answer (score -1):

How would GHC know what instance of `Monad` to use when you create a piece of data of type `A`?

Or, put another way, the type variable `m` isn't in scope on the left hand side of the type definition. That means it doesn't know what `m` should be, and can't work it out. It's implicit.

I'm sure there's some way you could do what you want to with an extension, probably using an explicit forall. (The RankNTypes extension), however we'd need to know what you were after a bit more.