# In Haskell, how to attach constraints to a parametric newtype, so that they automatically apply to any class instance that uses it?

Tags: haskell, constraints, typeclass, newtype

Assume I have a parametric type defined like this:

```hs
newtype FancyComplex a b = FancyComplex (a, b)
```

I intend to never use this newtype for any other parameters than numeric ones.
I mean that for whatever implementation I might do, I know that parameters `a` and `b` will always be an instance of `Num` .

I read in this question that you can do this:
[Can a typeclass constraint be used in a newtype definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43444170/can-a-typeclass-constraint-be-used-in-a-newtype-definition/43444407)

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
newtype (Num a, Num b) => FancyComplex a b = FancyComplex (a, b)
```

However this is not enough.
If I write any class like this:

```hs
class StupidClass x where add :: x -> x -> x
```

Then I should be able to write

```hs
instance StupidClass (FancyComplex a b) where
    add (FancyComplex (a, b)) (FancyComplex (a', b')) = FancyComplex (a+a', b+b')
```

But no GHC will tell me saying I did not enforce the `Num` requirement.
So I am forced to do this everytime:

```hs
instance (Num a, Num b) => StupidClass (FancyComplex a b) where
    add (FancyComplex (a, b)) (FancyComplex (a', b')) = FancyComplex (a+a', b+b')
```

All that writing the constraint in the newtype definition does, is force me to write the constraint explicitly every time. Ok this is still useful in case I forget.
But of course I would expect not to have to rewrite the constraint everytime.

How can I automatically and implicitly inherit constraints from the newtype definition?
Is this possible? if not, is there a reason why not?

Currently my weak workaround is to define a type alias `type FancyComplexReqs a b = (Num a, Num b)`

Thanks

Comment: Actually writing type constraints in the `newtype` is considered an misfeature if I recall correctly (https://books.google.be/books?id=nh0okI1a1sQC&pg=PA247&lpg=PA247#v=onepage&q&f=false). Writing the constraint is useful since it occurs in the signature of the `instance`, and thus also in the documentation. But if you do not restrict your type at the `newtype` level, it will be restricted due to the use of `(+)` in your definition.

Comment: But the newtype requirement might be stronger, and more beautifully expressed,  than the weaker and messier requirements of the instance itself. The thing is that if it is defined at the newtype level, I don't see any reason why it could not be automatically inherited, and documented in any instance that uses it. The point is that the newtype constraint could be fairly complicated and long to write and this saves space. My example is artifically constructed to illustrate my point, but in my code i have more complex structures, it's a pain to rewrite constraints every time.

Comment: You can write the minimum requirements for every instance, but that can be ugly. Sometimes I would rather write a more restrictive and uniform condition to apply on every instance. So that the whole thing looks more structured.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think this paper you show me says its bad, exactly because it has no solution to my question: hence my question.

Comment: @jam "You can write the minimum requirements for every instance, but that can be ugly. Sometimes I would rather write a more restrictive and uniform condition to apply on every instance" To address that need, I personally would just use the workaround you suggested (`type FancyComplexReqs a b = (Num a, Num b)`). You can also attach documentation explaining why these are a helpful group of constraints to impose everywhere.

Comment: @jam I would always want there to be *some* explicit annotation on the instance that it is making use of extra restrictions on its type variables; a constraint synonym keeps that to a tidy minimum, makes it obvious it's the same group of constraints everywhere, gives me a single point of control if I need to change the common group; it's exactly my personal optimum. Your desired syntax saves a few keypresses on writing every instance, but makes it less clear to read them, and gives you no possible "escape hatch" to write instances like `Functor` that require less constraints.

Comment: It is not recommended to constraint your datatype. Constraint functions that act on them instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can not be implemented, at least without changing the meaning of a `newtype`:

```
newtype (Num a, Num b) => FancyComplex a b = FancyComplex (a, b)

instance StupidClass (FancyComplex a b) where
    add (FancyComplex (a, b)) (FancyComplex (a', b')) = FancyComplex (a+a', b+b')
```

In the last line, `a+a'` needs function `+` which is a method of `Num`, so we need to have that at out disposal. I can only see these options:

1. The `+` function is stored inside the `FancyComplex` value. That would work, but the Haskell Report requires this `newtype` to have the same in-memory representation of a pair. There is no space for an additional pointer.
2. The `Num a, Num b` constraint is implicitly added to the instance definition since we need it in the implementation. This can work, but wouldn't it be better to be explicit about it? Having implicit constraints makes the instance harder to read, since there is a constraint even if there seems to be none.

Now, there is a possible alternative: if you want option 1, and you are fine with  a different runtime in-memory representation, then use a `data` instead:

```
data FancyComplex a b where
   FancyComplex :: (Num a, Num b) => a -> b -> FancyComplex a b
```

In this way each value will store its own pointers to the `Num` instance. It will require some more memory, but perhaps for your application this is not an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Encode the constraint in a GADT, like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data FancyComplex a b where
  FancyComplex :: (Num a, Num b) => a -> b -> FancyComplex a b

class StupidClass x where add :: x -> x -> x

instance StupidClass (FancyComplex a b) where
    add (FancyComplex a b) (FancyComplex a' b') = FancyComplex (a+a') (b+b')
```

You have to switch to `data` from `newtype` because constraints turn into dictionaries, which do have runtime representation. However, by doing so, we can get rid of your tuple, which saves as much as `data` costs.

Comment: But you've also added two new pointers ...

Comment: @luqui What I meant was referring to time cost, not memory cost. I guess that's not what I said, though.